# Errors Installing vagrant.berkshelf

Tags: ruby, vagrant, berkshelf

I working on a Windows 7 machine with Vagrant v 1.4.1 and I have been struggling to install the vagrant-berkshelf plugin.  I'm following some instructions from a [blog](http://misheska.com/blog/2013/06/16/getting-started-writing-chef-cookbooks-the-berkshelf-way/) by Mischa Taylor.    I've installed VirtualBox (4.2.20), a "sane" Ruby environment (with the DevKit) and the berkshelf gem and that went fine as well but whenever I issue the

```
> vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf
```

The command returns an error when trying to build the

```
Installing the 'vagrant-berkshelf' plugin. This can take a few minutes...

C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:62:in `run': 
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)

C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/bin/ruby.exe: invalid option -J  (-h will show valid
options) (RuntimeError)

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Users/user_me/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/hitimes-   
1.2.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Users/user_me/.vagrant.d/gems/gems/hitimes-1.2.1/ext/hitimes/c/gem_make.out
    from    
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:39:in `block in build'
```

if I issue

```
> gem install hitimes
```

that works fine, so the problem seems to be in the extension builder that Vagrant uses.  I don't have alot of experience working with Ruby I was just wanting to start learning to use chef and berkshelf with vagrant.

Comment: but the vagrant-berkshelf was installed ??

Comment: No the error installing hitimes caused the process to throw an exception and not install vagrant-berkshelf.  It has been awhile since I actually did get it to install but I still had to copy the hitimes library manually to get the plugin to work with vagrant.   I think it is primarily my current laptop config causing the installer to get confused as I use Cygwin and windows cmd as well.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the version of Ruby
try rvm to manage your ruby environments, download ruby 1.9.3 through rvm
then

```
rvm use 1.9.3
vagrant plugin install vagrant-berkshelf
```